# Closing workbook Saving changes Not working

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have build the following code

```
Sub Merge_File_based()
' Merge files based on Names

Dim AMITRETURN As String
Dim JPRETURN As String

Dim Folderpath As String
Dim counter1 As Integer
Dim counter2 As Integer
Dim Finalrow As Integer

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    sh = Sheets("First Step").Name

    Finalrow = Sheets(sh).Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False



    Folderpath = Fpath & "\"



    For counter1 = 2 To Finalrow Step 2
        counter2 = counter1 + 1


    AMITRETURN = wb.Sheets(sh).Cells(counter1, 1)
    JPRETURN = wb.Sheets(sh).Cells(counter2, 1)

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folderpath & AMITRETURN, UpdateLinks:=0
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folderpath & JPRETURN, UpdateLinks:=0


    Windows(JPRETURN).Activate

    Sheets(Array("AMIT Tax Return", "AMIT Tax Schedule")).Select
    Sheets("AMIT Tax Schedule").Activate
    Workbooks(JPRETURN).Sheets(Array("AMIT Tax Return", "AMIT Tax Schedule").Copy after:=Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Sheets("AMIT_form")

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents

    Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents

    Workbooks(JPRETURN).Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Next

    MsgBox "Task Complete"

End Sub
```

But when **Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Close SaveChanges:=True** runs in Loop it is not saving the workbook rather it asks me a question do you want to save workbook. If I answer yes, It gives error dochshare Integration not working etc. etc.

So I click no as i want to save the workbooks, once the macro is done looping through it allows me to save these files without any issue.

Also, when I step into the macro to see the error, it allows me to save file without any issue. Its only the loop that it creates problem, any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Ther's syntax error in line `Workbooks(JPRETURN).Sheets(Array("AMIT Tax Return", "AMIT Tax Schedule").Copy after:=Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Sheets("AMIT_form")` replace with `Workbooks(JPRETURN).Sheets(Array("AMIT Tax Return", "AMIT Tax Schedule")).Copy after:=Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Sheets("AMIT_form")` ( ")" was missing)  and see if it solved the probelm

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but the problem was I closed  the display alerts within before the entire loop was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should fix your problems, you enabled `.DisplayAlerts` within your loop, also your `.Select` and `.Activate` was unnecessary.
I'm not entirely sure if your `DoEvents` are needed, but I put them in the "correct" locations anyway

```
Option Explicit
Sub Merge_File_based()
' Merge files based on Names

Dim AMITRETURN As String
Dim JPRETURN As String

Dim Folderpath As String
Dim counter1 As Long
Dim counter2 As Long
Dim Finalrow As Long
Dim sh as Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("First Step")

Finalrow = sh.Range(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Folderpath = Fpath & "\"

For counter1 = 2 To Finalrow Step 2
    counter2 = counter1 + 1

    AMITRETURN = sh.Cells(counter1, 1)
    JPRETURN = sh.Cells(counter2, 1)

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folderpath & AMITRETURN, UpdateLinks:=0
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folderpath & JPRETURN, UpdateLinks:=0

    Workbooks(JPRETURN).Sheets(Array("AMIT Tax Return", "AMIT Tax Schedule")).Copy after:=Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Sheets("AMIT_form")

    Workbooks(AMITRETURN).Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    Workbooks(JPRETURN).Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Task Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh.. I made such a stupid mistake with display alert. I used select and activate to see if that will fix this or not but it didn't you are right I don't need this. I don't know what do events do but I read it some where that it might work hence I used it. Appreciate your help on this